# https in apache2traid

Tags: windows, apache, https

How do I configure apache to use https mode?
In other words, what should I do to make a certain page use https instead of http?

Answer (score 1):

here is an interessting Thread for you:

[Virtual Hosts with SSL](http://apache2triad.net/forums/archive/o_t__t_1259__how-to-setup-virtual-hosts-with-ssl.html)